# implementing Observer Pattern as MarketData observer

Tags: c++, qt, design-patterns, observer-pattern, algorithmic-trading

I am developing GUI form in Qt and I wonder how to implement ObserverPattern. Form can subscribe to many data streams distinguished by tickerId, when data stream arrives (new quote is available) my PosixClient (socket wrapper) fires `notifyObservers()` method what results in `update()` method of observer being executed.

### BUT:

this `update()` method is `void update()` and I need to take incoming data records and plot them, count something, just use them. So how can I achieve this, how pass data records to observer? 
Data is available to Observable (MarketData object derived from Observable). When data arrives I push it into this Observable and notify observers.

```
void PosixClient::tickPrice( TickerId tickerId, TickType field, double price, int canAutoExecute) {
    printf("tradingclient_1: tickPrice: \n");
    for(std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<MarketData> >::iterator it=dataRepository.begin(); 
            it!=dataRepository.end(); it++){
        if((*it)->tickerId==tickerId){
            (*it)->tickPriceData.push_back(tickSizeRecord(field,price,canAutoExecute));
            (*it)->notifyObservers();
            //TODO: start thread to store incoming data in repository
        }
    }
}
```

Their `void update()` methods are then called. in order to retrieve a data from this function I decided to pass a function pointer `boost::function<>` to it as a callback and Observer calls this function pointer that points to my GUI object with incoming data from observable as argument. **Is this right approach?**

```
struct MarketData : public QuantLib::Observable {
//public:
    MarketData();
    MarketData(IB::Contract c, int tickerId):c(c),tickerId(tickerId){}
    MarketData(const MarketData& orig);
    virtual ~MarketData();
    std::vector<IB::Record> tickPriceData; //market data fed in tickPrice
//private:
    IB::Contract c;
    int tickerId;
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<MarketData> pMyObservable;
typedef boost::function<void (int tickerId, IB::Record record)> f_action_ptr;

class MarketDataObserver : public QuantLib::Observer{
public:
    MarketDataObserver(pMyObservable obs, f_action_ptr ptr)
        : observable(obs), f_ptr(ptr){
      this->registerWith(observable);
    }
    MarketDataObserver(const MarketDataObserver &observer)
      : Observer(observer),
        observable(observer.observable){ // faction_ptr is not copied!
    }

    void update(){
        data=observable->tickPriceData.back();
        //printf("new data: %l\n",data.price);
        f_ptr(observable->tickerId, data);
    }
private:
    IB::Record data;
    pMyObservable observable;
    f_action_ptr f_ptr;
};
```

---

PLEASE NOTE:

I am aware of Qt signal/slot mechanism, but in my opinion Qt signal/slot is not at all solution here, when I need dynamically subscribe to data, plot them, show on Qt Form, then delete subscription when Form is canceled. But maybe I am wrong. Am I? I ask for real, working examples, from life, not theoretical dispute.

Comment: Qt already used signals and slots. Which from my understand can be used in place of the observer pattern.

Comment: no, this is not a response for a click but I have to send incoming data to any object that subscribed to it. Can you show example?

Answer (score 1):

The usual Qt idiom for the observer pattern are indeed signals and slots. Have the source of the data emit signals *and pass the data as an argument of the signal*. That's how this is done within Qt -- signals are not used just for the GUI events.

Comment: can you show example? I think signal/slot mechanism can't be used in this situation. Note: I need to subscribe to data dynamically, when user requests data from some form, then my Socket wrapper has to send this data to form when tickPrice callback is fired by API. I feel like I need to store observers of observable data streams, or even if signal/slot mechanism might be used for this - wouldn't it ends up being the same?

Comment: One example might be to have multiple signals, each for one type of a notification (these will obviously have to be defined at compile time). Your clients would then ``connect`` to a subset of these signals based on the user's preference in what they're interested. Of course, you actually *can* (sort-of) add these signals and slots at runtime, but manipulating the ``QMetaObject`` is probably something which suggests that another approach shall be taken.

Comment: In general, use whatever fits your use case best -- if you need to define new types of events on the fly, then perhaps Qt's signals are not the way to go. Instead, you could manage a list of known event kinds and for each of them a list of receivers. This could again be implemented in many ways in C++ -- the result won't be very Qt-ish, but it will work.

Comment: In my opinion Qt signal/slot is not at all solution here, when I need dynamically subscribe to data. I am not sure if you understand my problem. Maybe you think about something but haven't faced the problem in practice so you think slots are all you need.

Comment: I'm not sure what part of "perhaps Qt's signals are not the way to go" led you to an impression that I think that "slots are all you need", sorry.

Comment: so Jan, what is your opinion in the end: are slots what I need? I feel no. And have you tried do something like this? if yes, have you used slots? I feel like you haven't and you give answer me who asks and tries to do it. Please be specific, an example should follow your statements.

Comment: Nope, I have not ever written an application which deals with stock pricing. I also have no idea what is the best thing for you, and I won't provide a detailed example tailored to your specific situation. Signals/slots are not the answer to everything, and I have used other ways of message passing when needed (see e.g. https://projects.kde.org/projects/extragear/pim/trojita/repository/revisions/master/entry/src/Imap/Parser/Response.h#L222) -- sometimes one might want to use C++ type system in this way (see the handleXYZ methods in Imap::Mailbox::ImapTask and Imap::Mailbox::Model and the PLUG m